# Correctly protect a JSON value for PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, json, postgresql

I encoded with c++ a json file with some special characters :

```
{
  "key":"\+&~#@"
}
```

and I have the following error when I try to store this in my postgreSQL database :

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Escape sequence "\+" is invalid.
```

What would be the correct c++ way of protecting this value in JSON so postgreSQL would not complain about invalid sequences ?

Comment: Try double backslash to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Try double backslash to escape the backslash.  Without that, it thinks you are escaping the plus sign.

Comment: So I have to parse the string and add "\\" to every "\" I see ?

Comment: Can you please post some code so it is clear what you are actually doing.